# SPARQL query to retrieve all objects and properties

Tags: sparql, ontology, sesame

Using the [Wine ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-guide/wine.rdf), I want to create SPARQL query so I can retrieve **all wines** and **their properties** like the table below - consider that I don't know the properties' names *a priori*.

```
vin                  | rdf:type     | vin:hasMaker      |  vin:hasSugar   | ...
==========================================================================  ...
GaryFarrellMerlot    |  vin:Merlot  | vin:Elyse         |  vin:Dry        | ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ElyseZinfandel       |  vin:Elyse   | vin:GaryFarrell   |  vin:Dry        | ...
...
```

Can someone give me a hint?

-- **EDIT**

It is not possible to have the query result in the format I mentioned, but I can have it this way:

```
vin                |   property     |  value
=================================================
GaryFarrellMerlot  |   rdf:type     |  vin:Merlot
-------------------------------------------------
GaryFarrellMerlot  |   rdf:hasMaker |  vin:Elyse
-------------------------------------------------
...
```

With this select (thanks [cygri](https://stackoverflow.com/users/346336/cygri)):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?wine ?property ?value
WHERE { 
       ?o1 a ?class .
       ?wine a ?o1 .
       ?wine ?property ?value .
}
```

This will take wines instead of type of wines (Merlot -> GaryFarrellMerlot). The only problem is it takes wine but also Winery, Regions, Flavours, etc and I wanted only wines and its properties. Besides, there's **no** such attribute **vin:Merlot rdfs:subClassOf vin:Wine.** Any hint?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't. You need to know beforehand what columns you want in your query result.

Listing all properties of wines isn't very hard of course:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?property
WHERE { 
    ?wine a vin:Wine .
    ?wine ?property ?value .
}
```

Then you need to write some code that creates the final SPARQL query from the list of results.

Comment: Well, the wine ontology is not a simple RDF model but a complex OWL ontology. So to do more complex things, like inferring that Merlot is a subclass of Wine, you need an OWL reasoner (or probably a triple store that supports OWL).